# G Suite: Erase local user Profile in Chromebook

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-directory-api, chromebook

i'm wondering if there is a way (through script or anything) to remotely remove the local profile of a user on a Chromebook managed through the Google-Admin-Console ? 
[GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/GAM3DirectoryCommands#chrome-os-devices) has no option for that. and the Google-Admin-Console doesn't provide such option

Comment: There is the option of deleting the device itself from the domain using the [admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/mobiledevices/delete), however, if you have more than one profile in the device they will all be removed. The only way to remove individual ones is manually doing it.

Comment: Deleting the device itself is not a solution for me, because we have to enroll the device again in our domain. And this is not practical for remote troubleshooting

Comment: Agreed, it would be problematic, you'll have to do it manually.

Comment: @AMolina yes but, i can't do it, because the user in another city. So manually is not an option

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this, it's not the best solution, but it has solved the problem the user were facing.

In the admin console i have created a new OU and changed it's policy, so that when a user log out from the Chromebook in this OU, his local data will be erased automatically.

in this way i have deleted his local profile remotely and after he could log in successfully again, i moved his Chromebook back to the standard OU.